# Get event of Home key long press when screen is locked?

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which I have to control the Home key long press when the screen is in locked mode to perform an action.Is there any possible way to do this.Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

This key is handled by the framework, so your application can't handle it.